# Declare two pointer on integer (VS2012)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

When I declared one pointer on integer, my program is work fine.
But if I declare another pointer, I get error when my program executing.

Why?

I use VC++ 11;

Example code:

```
int main()
{
    int *p_first;
    int *p_seconds;

    *p_first = 5;
    *p_seconds = 6;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
int a = 3;
```

in memory, you are creating a space, calling it `a`, and assigning the value of `3` to it.

[image]

When you write

```
int* b = new int(3);
```

you are creating a space `b` **that points to** a newly created space to which the value `3` is assigned.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to make your pointers point to some memory you can write to. You are dereferencing uninitialized pointers, which is *undefined behaviour*. Your first version might have "worked fine", but it is still broken and cannot be relied on to work.

```
int* p_first; // uninitialized pointer.
int i = 41;   //
p_first = &i; // p_first now points to location of i
*p_first = 5; // OK

p_first = new int(); // p_first points to dynamically allocated int
*p_first = 5; // OK
delete p_first;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer. This is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). It worked the first time because you were lucky.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is free to do whatever it wants - your program has undefined behavior since you dereference uninitialized pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you are trying to **dereference an *uninitialized pointer*** that leads to undefined behavior. Try like this:

```
int *p_first;
int x = 5;
p_first = &x;
```